# How to compare coordinates in two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

df1

| x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1240 | 1755 | label1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1240 | 2 | label2 |

df2

| x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 992.0 | 943.0 | 1166.0 | 974.0 | tex1 |
| 1110.0 | 864.0 | 1166.0 | 890.0 | text2 |

Based on a condition like the following:

```
if df1['x1'] >= df2['x1'] or df1['y1'] >= df2['y1']:
   # I want to add a new column 'text' in df1 with the text from df2.
   df1['text'] = df2['text']
```

What's more, it is possible in `df2` to have more than one row that makes the above-mentioned condition `True`, so I will need to add another `if` statement for df2 to get the best match.

My problem here is not the conditions but how am I supposed to approach the interaction between both data frames. Any help, or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: it's not clear what you what do you want to compare.. Have the dataframes the same length and you want to compare each row 1-1? Do you want to compare each row from df1 with each row of df2?

Comment: I want to compare each row from df1 with each row of df2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate from df1 through every row of df2 and return a match you can do it with the `.apply()` function in `df1` and use the `df2` as lookup table.

NOTE: In the above example I return the first match (by using the `.iloc[0]`) not all the matches.

Create two dummy dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 3], 'y1': [1, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [11, 1, 13], 'y1': [3, 52, 26], 'text': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']})
```

Create a lookup function

```
def apply_condition(row, df):
    condition  = ((row['x1'] >= df['x1']) | (row['y1'] >= df['y1']))
    return df[condition]['text'].iloc[0] # ATTENTION: Only the first match return
```

Create new column and print results

```
df1['text'] = df1.apply(lambda row: apply_condition(row, df2), axis=1)
df1.head()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It might not be the best idea to have `df2` as a global variable in your function.

Comment: This is not a problem :-) I changed my solution and I used the df2 as argument. Is the solution ok now?